# Django(1.9.6) list_display works on dev not prod

Tags: python, django

I am running a local version of django on my computer as well as a django droplet at DigitalOcean, both Django 1.9.6. However, everything I have done this far has been the same across these two environment, but when I tried to customize the admin screen, it only worked on my local env.

The change I did was to add the following code to the app/admin.py.

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('post_title', 'pub_date', 'is_premium', 'source_title')
    list_filter = ['pub_date', 'source_title', 'is_premium']


admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

But this customization is only shown on my local env... I have of course pulled and updated my code on DigitalOcean using Git. Just to make that clear.

[Screenshot of local environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLMV4.png)

[Screenshot of DigitalOcean environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEufV.png)

Comment: Are you sure version are the same? Even look of admin isn't same. Also you should restart your application server on production and not only pull from git.

Comment: One is running python 2..7 while the other is running 3.5. Maybe this functionality is only available in one of the versions.

Comment: The thing isn't in python version. It seems that your production django either not 1.9 or you just forgot to update things. For example restart your supervisor workers or restart uwsgi or gunicorn. Such things.

Comment: I needed to restart gunicorn. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to restart gunicorn. Thanks to valentjedi for providing the answer in the comments.